# How do I prevent other iCloud devices from activating internet sharing?

Tags: iphone, ios, icloud, wifi, internet-sharing

On my iPhone 8 on iOS 16 I've disabled (or so I thought) internet sharing in settings. When I look for WiFi networks on my iPhone 6 however it presents my iPhone 8 there regardless, and if I try to connect it succeeds.

Now, you might argue that I've only turned off internet sharing with a switch labeled "allow others to connect" (freely translated), which doesn't include iCloud devices (logged into same account), but when I connect using an iCloud device that same switch *turns on by itself*.

The conclusions I've drawn are:

1. The switch is relevant to iCloud devices, otherwise it would've stayed off
2. The switch isn't respected with regard to iCloud devices

**How do I prevent other iCloud devices from being able to activate internet sharing on my iPhone?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't.

Apple created this "feature" to streamline the process of connecting to an associated hot spot (same AppleID signed in) to make things easier.

The only way that I have found to prevent the hot spot from being found is to make the user a Standard User and enabling the "Require Administrator Authorization" (under the Advanced menu) for switching networks.

I created a standard account (called Test User) and signed into my iCloud account.  When I did this, the hot spot was nowhere to be found, achieving the goal.    While the addresses the question, it's quite a substantial work around to lose admin privileges just to prevent automatic connection.

Comment: Interesting, and here we're still only talking macOS. To prevent this on iOS devices even more hoops would have to be jumped through, presumably. I'll accept it in few days assuming no conflicting answers appear.

Comment: I went through the settings on the iPhone, the only option to turn it off has the fine print "Allow other users or devices **not signed into iCloud**  to look for your shared network."  As long as you're connected to iCloud, you can share this connection.  So, you can disable it for other users, but not for devices/users you're supposedly aware of

Comment: Disabling Bluetooth completely on the sharing device would seem like the easiest compromise

Comment: What do you do when you'd like to use a headphone/headset with your iPhone @Andreas?

Comment: I grab an iPhone 5 or 6 and plug them in because those have freakin' headphone jacks. Or just enable Bluetooth, because, as mentioned, it's a compromise. A proper solution would've been nice but I won't hold my breath considering Apple seems to have lost their ability to compensate for things they don't know about.

Comment: Getting a device with an IOS that's 4 versions out of date is a better workaround?  I have my hotspot available on all of my devices and I've never had an issue with it.  I'm not seeing why this is such an issue to be resolved

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "Getting a device with an IOS that's 4 versions out of date is a better workaround?" Is that a suggestion, or a question? If the latter: There is no workaround that I'm aware of; I mentioned a compromise, which is a trade-off. That compromise (of which you've identified one downside) requires flipping a switch — no device acquisition is necessary, although the existence of my iPhone 6 is already mentioned in the question. So far, no one has shown interest in the underlying issue, so I've had no reason to touch upon it and I understand your confusion.

Comment: To sate your curiosity I draw analogues to the awareness of possibility for internet access and this phenomenon (first random link I found): https://news.utexas.edu/2017/06/26/the-mere-presence-of-your-smartphone-reduces-brain-power/ It turns out to be a little tricky to create an environment without that possibility.